# Check C and C++ shared library linker dependencies from Python

Tags: python, c++, c, shared-libraries

Is there a way of getting the shared libraries linked from .dll's .dylib's, .so's, .pyd's directly from Python? I'm looking for the information that I get from otool -L on Mac and dumpbin /DEPENDENTS for MSVC

Comment: For macOS, look at https://pypi.org/project/macholib/

Comment: I'll look into it but I was really hoping for something cross-platform?